# Building python library in conda environment sets default RPATH in .so file

Tags: python, conda, setup.py, distutils, pybind11

I am working on building a python library with some C++ extensions using a setup.py
and pybind11. Since my C++ extensions depend on some shared libraries, I want these pure c++ libraries to be automatically found when importing the Python module.
I did some research and came to the idea to set the `rpath` value to the folder where these libraries are stored (using LD_LIBRARY_PATH or LD_PRELOAD is not an option).

So basically in my setup.py I added additional linker options for the Extensions module:

```
linker_opts = ['-Wl,-rpath=path/to/my/lib']
Extension('python_module', extra_link_args=linker_opts)
```

For some reason this approach didn't work and after some research I found out that
in a conda environment the `-rpath` is already set to something like `~/miniconda/envs/dev/lib` so adding this path twice doesn't work.

I checked this with `readelf -d somemodule.so` and it turns out when switching to a simple python environment this is not an issue at all, so it seems Conda somehow sets up this `rpath` by default.

I checked the conda documentation and didn't found anything regarding this,
so is there some easy way to disable this default rpath valule?

UPDATE: Regarding installation I use `python setup.py install`.

**UPDATE2:**

Meanwhile I found out that this flag is generated from the distutils
version inside the conda environment. In particular

```
In [31]: distutils.sysconfig.get_config_vars('LDSHARED')
Out[31]: ['gcc -pthread -shared -B /.../miniconda3/envs/dev   /compiler_compat -L/../miniconda3/envs/dev/lib -Wl,-rpath=/./miniconda3/envs/dev/lib -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--sysroot=/']
```

I'm just curious if this has something todo with different distutils versions. The one used in conda is 3.8.10, if I use the system python3.9 its 3.9.5.
It seems also one option is, that conda somewhere exports `LD_SHARED` but im not sure where...

Comment: These settings are specific to the compiler package you install. The `conda-forge::compilers` set up a bunch of stuff inside activation scripts which will be at `dev/etc/conda/activate.d/*.sh`. If you look through those scripts you'll likely find settings that are affecting the behavior observed.

Comment: There is no activate.d/ folder in dev/etc.. do you mean `dev/lib/python3.8/scripts/common`?

Comment: No, I wrote it as intended. For example, in one of my environments I have `miniconda3/envs/kallisto-build/etc/conda/activate.d/activate_clang_osx-64.sh` adds things like `-Wl,-rpath,${PREFIX}/lib` to various `LDFLAGS*` variables. Are you using a Conda compiler?

Comment: Setuptools uses gcc according to the build output. Keep in mind this is not a conda specific build its basically just executing a `python setup.py install` so basically its building a bdist. Unforntunately I am not able to find this folder you mentioned..

Comment: I guess you also use the clang compiler from conda thats why this path exists

Comment: Not sure, but if Python is from Conda, it may have internally set `LDSHARED` as part of compiling Python, and this might persist when Python runs compilation. For example, there is definitely [stuff being done with `LDSHARED` in the Conda Forge build of Python](https://github.com/conda-forge/python-feedstock/search?q=LDSHARED).